# extract the string between last open tag and first closed tag in android

Tags: java, android, string, tags

I want to get the string between tag like below

For example:

Input
      `<p><b><i><u>hello</u></i></b>prajakta</p>`

output :`hello`

i want to get only strings

`<u>hello</u>` this should be the output as it is starting with `<u>` and ending with `</u>`

Comment: So, you're wanting the output to be `prajakta`, is that right?

Comment: no,it should be `hello` because it  has started and ended with same tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this -

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String stringToSearch = "<p><b><i><u>hello</u></i></b>prajakta</p>";

    // the pattern we want to search for
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<p><b><i><u>(\\S+)</u></i></b>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);

    // if we find a match, get the group 
    if (m.find()) {

      // get the matching group
      String codeGroup = m.group(1);

      // print the group
      System.out.format("'%s'\n", codeGroup);

    }

  }
```

**Output** - 'hello'

Comment: thank you !! but string will not always be same .There can be different tags and number  of tags can also be different.